# Good opensource JS project for learning?

Tags: javascript

I have learned basic JS knowledge, and read "Javascript definitive guide" book, but best way to improve is learning by doing, so any opensource project for practice, or any good suggestion for improving JS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As an example of an open source project you could look into I would recommend to check the [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org) sources. It's easier to grasp the advanced concepts there than e.g. in JQuery since there is a much wider code base for many different aspects. There is a lot to go through in the dojox packages. The code is also nicely documented, and recently they added nice online documentation, too, something that was missing for a long time. I learned a lot by peeking into dojo's internals, so I can only recommend it.

You should pay attention to their way of coding object-orientedly and how it differs from what plain JS offers you.

In addition to great code you can learn the concepts of code minification there, which is a big deal for the dojo project. There's also material on unit testing with Javascript code, something that is often overlooked but as important as back-end unit tests imo.

By reading "Javascript - The definitive guide" you now know a good bit about the language itself and its usage for browser-based applications. But with the recent popularity gain of Javascript it has also found its application on the server side. E.g. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is a very interesting project you could look into.

The concept of "Closures" is something you could look up, then find examples in existing code and finally use them in your own.

"Ajax" is another buzzword and concept you should be familiar with, it lets you do all the nice things in your browser that some years ago were only possible in desktop applications.

Modern web applications make heavy use of Javascript, but since standard Javascript and its prototypical inheritance are a bit clumsy to use, frameworks were written that simplify common tasks. You should familiarize with one or more of them to get an understanding of what they simplify compared to plain Javascript - this way you will automatically learn the drawbacks and shortcomings of pure Javascript. A good example is the `with` keyword. It's there, but nobody uses it. If your time just allows you to delve into one of these frameworks then my recommendation would be [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) - it's the most widely used Javascript framework out there.

**Some Frameworks**

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)
- [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org)
- [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/)
- [YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/)
- [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org)
- [Ext.js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

Read [blogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409056/top-rated-javascript-blogs) and technical articles on the web, skim through Javascript questions here at Stackoverflow to keep up to date and learn about interesting corner cases.

**Some book recommendations**

- [Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/)
- [ppk on Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321423305)
- [JavaScript - The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)
- [Pro Javascript Techniques](http://jspro.org/)
- [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)
- [Ajax in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394613)
- [Ajax in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394990)
- [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault2/)
- [Dojo - The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516487)
- [Test-Driven Javascript Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321683919)

Comment: thank you! You give an elaborate introduction.

Comment: could you give me some advice about how to read dojo source code? I have no idea about which directory starts.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jason: Before diving into the sources I would recommend looking at the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/) first, to get their concepts, especially how they do inheritance. Once you mastered that I would recommend to start with a topic in dojox that you are interested in. dojox projects tend to be implemented on a higher level than those in dojo core, so I find the learning curve is less steep there.

Comment: :thanks, I will try this way.

Comment: :hi，in recent months, I read some books you recommended, they're really helpful. I just can't wait to use the knowledge in the real project. I want to mimic some small project and modify their features, I believe in this way, I can improve my JS much faster. Could you recommend some sites?

Answer (score 2):

I used the "Javascript definitive guide" as a dictionary,there're still other excellent books you may have to dive into like "High Perfomance JavaScript" "Javascript:The Good Parts".....there're plenty of small demos in these books that you can do something over it and If I were you ,I would implemented some of my ideas by using javascript